# VHDL IF statement inside process statement

Tags: fpga, vhdl, xilinx

I am learning VHDL. I have doubt regarding execution of `If Else` inside `process` statement. My code is :

```
entity test is

port(

      clk          : in std_logic;
      reset        : in std_logic;
      enable       : in std_logic;
      a            :in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
      b            :out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
       );    
  end test;
 

 architecture test_behave of test is     
        signal temp1:std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        type states is (state1,state2);
       signal present_state:states;
          
        begin     
     process(clk,reset)
         begin
             if(reset='1')  then
    
                temp1<=(others=>'0');
                present_state<=state1;
                 
             elsif(rising_edge(clk))  then             
                     case present_state  is
                     
                        when state1=>       
                             if(enable='1') then--- if fir_enable='1' then NLMS block is enabled     
                                   temp1<=a;                            
                                  present_state<=state2;
                             else
                                  present_state<=state1;
                              end if;
                              
                        when state2=>
                        
                                 b<=temp1;
                                 present_state<=state1;
                    end case;
           end if;
 end process;
 end test_behave;
```

Then I have added a testbench for evaluating this module. In that testbench, `reset` is high for first clock cycle and `enable` is low. At that time, present state is `state1`. Then in the next clock cycle, `reset` is made low and `enable` is made high and input data is given to `a`. The present state became `state2`. However `temp1` variable didn't get the value of `a` in the same clock cycle even though both `temp1` and present state are both signals.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Temp is assigned on the first clock edge where all three of:

- Enable = true
- A has a value
- Present_state = state1

exactly as the code specifies.